# ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function IPS\Theme\class_game_front_admincp::dashboard()

Tags: php, html

I have forum Invision Power Suite and error in app.

```
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function IPS\Theme\class_game_front_admincp::dashboard(), 9 passed in /home/ltrpplp/www/system/Theme/SandboxedTemplate.php on line 61 and exactly 10 expected in /home/ltrpplp/www/system/Theme/Theme.php(860) : eval()'d code:1440
```

Main.php:

```
protected function _dashboard()
{
    $Count_Characters = \IPS\game\AdminCP::Dashboard_Count_Characters();
    $Count_Groups = \IPS\game\AdminCP::Dashboard_Count_Groups();
    $Count_Items = \IPS\game\AdminCP::Dashboard_Count_Items();
    $Count_Cars = \IPS\game\AdminCP::Dashboard_Count_Vehicles();
    $Count_Doors = \IPS\game\AdminCP::Dashboard_Count_Doors();
    $Count_Areas = \IPS\game\AdminCP::Dashboard_Count_Areas();
    $Count_Objects = \IPS\game\AdminCP::Dashboard_Count_Objects();
    $Count_Pickups = \IPS\game\AdminCP::Dashboard_Count_Pickups();
    $Count_Money = \IPS\game\AdminCP::Dashboard_Count_Money();
    $Count_MoneyBank = \IPS\game\AdminCP::Dashboard_Count_MoneyBank();
    return \IPS\Theme::i()->getTemplate('admincp')->dashboard( $Count_Characters, $Count_Groups, $Count_Items, $Count_Cars, $Count_Doors, $Count_Areas, $Count_Objects, $Count_Pickups, $Count_Money, $Count_MoneyBank );
}



    public function Dashboard_Count_MoneyBank()
{
    try
    {
        $result = \IPS\Db::i()->select( 'count(`char_bankcash`)', 'ipb_characters')->first();
    }
    catch( \UnderflowException $e )
    {
        \IPS\Output::i()->error( 'no_module_permission', '2C122/1', 403, '' );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And have:

```
Bank in Cash: 6$
```

Although I have over $ 10,000 in mysql..
How to fix this? Help me please! :(

Comment: That is not the correct code part. You can see the file in the error message. You call a function with 9 parameters, but one is missing.